# Databinding issues with programmatically added DataTemplate and DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Iam trying to create a Datatemplate for DataGrid programmatically.
Iam able to do so. But iam stuck at a position. The binding of DataGrid is not working.
I think there is some issues with binding. Here is the output Iam getting :

[image: Output Screenshot]

3rd column in the image is empty although I have set the binding for that column.

Here is the XAML file  :

```
<Window x:Class="NestedListViewDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">

<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Loaded="myDataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="templatecolumnId" Header="Id" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="templatecolumnName" Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="templateColumnInnerTable" Header="InnerTable" />
    </Datagrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
       </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have Added Three columns and in 3rd column iam trying to add another datagrid programmatically.
Here is the Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGrid innergrid = new DataGrid();

            InnerClass ic=new InnerClass();
            ic.InnerData="InnerXYZ";
        innergrid.Items.Add(ic);

            AddressClass ac = new AddressClass();
            ac.Id = "1";
            ac.Name = "XYZ";
            ac.setDatagrid(innergrid);
            myDataGrid.Items.Add(ac);

            myDataGrid.MinRowHeight = 100;
            myDataGrid.MinColumnWidth = 250;

        }
    public void myDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
            tbHolder1.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Id"));
            dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder1;
            dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
            templatecolumnId.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

            dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            tbHolder2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder2;
            dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
            templatecolumnName.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

            dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder3 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGrid));
            tbHolder3.SetBinding(DataGrid.DataContextProperty, new Binding("Address"));
            tbHolder3.SetValue(DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumnsProperty, true);
            dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder3;
            dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
            templateColumnInnerTable.CellTemplate = dataTemplate1;

        }
    public class AddressClass
    {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            private DataGrid address;
            public DataGrid Address
            {
                get { return address; }
            }
            public void setDatagrid(DataGrid dtnew)
            {
                this.address = dtnew;
            }

        }
    public class InnerClass
        {
            public string InnerData{ get; set; }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why you doing all that stuff in code behind? That's for what XAML is for.

Comment: All I wanted to do is create nested ListView/DataGrid of n-levels. And  level is decided at runtime. Hence I thought of doing this in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always needs to set a `Collection` for the `DataGrid`. I had made some changes to your existing code which works fine. Please see the below snippet

Modified your `AddressClass` by adding a `Collection` of `AddressClass`. This property needs to bind with the `DataGrid`.

```
public class Address
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address() { }
}

public class AddressClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }

    public AddressClass()
    {
        Address = new List<Address>();
    }
    public void AddItems(Address item)
    {
        Id = item.Id;
        Name = item.Name;
        Address.Add(item);
    }
}
public class InnerClass
{
    public string InnerData { get; set; }
}
```

Modified your template to bind the `DataGrid`. Please notice that I have binded the `Collection` to `ItemsSource` property instead of `DataContext` property

```
public void myDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
        tbHolder1.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Id"));
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder1;
        dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
        templatecolumnId.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

        dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        tbHolder2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder2;
        dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
        templatecolumnName.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

        dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder3 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGrid));
        tbHolder3.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Address"));
        tbHolder3.SetValue(DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumnsProperty, true);
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder3;
        dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
        templateColumnInnerTable.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
    }
```

Changes in Calling method

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGrid innergrid = new DataGrid();

        InnerClass ic = new InnerClass();
        ic.InnerData = "InnerXYZ";
        innergrid.Items.Add(ic);

        Address ac = new Address() { Id = "100",Name ="Vimal" };
        Address ac1 = new Address(){Id ="101", Name= "Vimal 1"};
        AddressClass add = new AddressClass();
        add.AddItems(ac);
        add.AddItems(ac1);
        myDataGrid.Items.Add(add);

        myDataGrid.MinRowHeight = 100;
        myDataGrid.MinColumnWidth = 250;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton bro. It worked. I would love to subscribe your blogs for updates.